# Can we create and load VR model (Objects, Conference Room) in Android NDK with Google Cardboard SDK without using unity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, google-cardboard, google-vr-sdk

Using the sample code of [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart) I can able to load and run the app in my device as image is attached from Android Studio without using unity but not able to get proper resources and documents how to load [conference room](https://poly.google.com/view/bZd25AAUgCu) from a poly object in Android NDK.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the example, everything you need should be given.
However, you need Obj as file format and the surfaces must be triangles.

The conference room you have selected does not correspond to this format.
You can now either convert your conference room to the obj format or read in the gltf format and write your own parser based on it.
Easier would be probably the first one because there are already many solutions for it.